# Get the day of the given date to exclude from the difference between two dates

Tags: java, date

I want to exclude sunday from the differences between two dates.
I have used the following code to get the differences between two dates:

```
leaveDuration  = (int)( (leavetodate.getTime() - leavefromdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
```

Now I want toexclude sunday between the two dates. Or for that matter I want to exclude a holiday in general.
How should the above code be modified to get the desired result?

Comment: So you're looking for a setup that excludes all Sundays from the calendar as well as defined holidays?  I think you're going to need more than that one line of code.

Comment: Yes. How should I go about it?

Comment: Beware that your code doesn't account for leap days/seconds, etc.; consider using a time library such as [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do I need to include jar file for joda-time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Calendar

```
int getDiff(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(fromDate);
    int workDays = 0;
    while (c.getTime().before(toDate)) {
        if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            workDays++;
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return workDays;
}
```

Comment: `if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)` should also take into account holidays, something like: `if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && !holidayCalendar.isNonWorkingDay(c.getTime()))`, where `holidayCalendar` is a delegate that knows about the holidays for the particular territory of execution.